# <p-calendar disable all dates and need to enable only few date ranges (multiple minDate and maxDate)

Tags: angular, primeng

minDt >>  Sat Jan 11 2020 08:00:00
maxDt >>  Wed Jan 13 2020 08:00:00

minDt >>  Thu Jan 16 2020 08:00:00
maxDt >>  Sat Jan 18 2020 08:00:00

minDt >>  Sun Jan 23 2020 08:00:00
maxDt >>  Tue Jan 25 2020 08:00:00

```
   <p-calendar id="calender"  (onSelect)="_loadTimeSlot()" [readonlyInput]="false" [(maxDate)]="maxDateSat" [(minDate)]="minDateSat" class="pc-f-calendar" inputId="timeSlotDate" formControlName="timeSlotDate"
    [dateFormat]="calendarDateFormat" [locale]="calendarLocale" [placeholder]="calendarHolder" appendTo="body" showIcon="true"
    [monthNavigator]="true"  [yearNavigator]="true"  yearRange="1970:2100"
    [showOnFocus]="true" (onFocus)="_onFocus($event)">
  </p-calendar>
```

Comment: You can use disabledDates property on  ```<p-calendar```.

Answer (score 3):

As per prime documentation you can add disabledDates (Array of date values) and/or disabledDays (Array of days). There is no option to disable multiple min and max dates (multiple date ranges to disable).

[PrimeNG Calendar](https://primeng.org/calendar#api.calendar.props.disabledDays)

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" [disabledDates]="invalidDates" [disabledDays]="[0,6]" [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: I couldn't find it in the documentation and the link does not work, BUT it worked! [disabledDays]="[0,6]" disabled Sundays and Saturdays. [disabledDays]="[1,2,3,4,5]" disabled Mo-Fr !

Comment: @MikhailRatner updated the documentation link